# Emacs / Slime / Clojure / Browser Tree

Tags: emacs, ide, clojure, slime

I was recently playing with CounterClockwise (a Clojure plugin for Eclipse).
One thing I really liked about CounterClockwise was that:

- center panel = code
- left panel = file system tree
- right panel = showed a list of all defns/defs of the current file

I'm currently using Emacs/Slime. Question: is there something that provides a similar setup? I would prefer the left/right panel/buffers to be "permenant", i.e. to still stay alive even when I press C-x 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar windows setup with [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/), but [CEDET](http://cedet.sf.net) currently lacks Clojure support, so no tags will be shown :-(